# angular google map different markers for types of markers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-places-api, angular-google-maps

i'm using angular google map to render map and i'm using googleplaces for search and display nearby locations as markers. all i want is display different markers for different places. for example i have a collection of 20 markers of different types, if i have schools in that i have to highlight it with a school marker. my code is
controller:-

```
var displayStoreMarkers = function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               var place = results[i];
               $scope.markers.push({
                      id: i,
                      coords: {
                         latitude: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                         longitude: place.geometry.location.lng()
                      },
                      data: 'hospital,school,accounting,airport,amusement_park,atm,bakery,bank,bar,cafe,church,food,hindu_temple',
                      name: place.types
               });
            }
          }
          $scope.$apply();
          $scope.length=results.length;
          $scope.place = results;
     }
```

and html:-

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options" control="mapControl">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'coords'">
        <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>{{name}}</div>
        </ui-gmap-windows>
    </ui-gmap-markers>  
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `options.icon` of `<ui-gmap-marker>` directive or `typeOptions` of `<ui-gmap-markers>` directive.

See docs:

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers